# "command not found: pyenv" when opening terminal

Tags: pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

Some time ago I installed and used `pyenv` for a purpose I don't need anymore. Then, I uninstalled it. However, whenever I open up my terminal the first thing it prints is:

`/Users/jcortizrh/.zshrc:1: command not found: pyenv`

So it looks like my terminal is still trying to use `pyenv`. How can I fix this? I tried editing the `.zshrc` file but it looks complicated and I'm afraid of modifying it and ruining my terminal somehow.

EDIT: my `.zshrc` looks like this:

```
PATH=$(pyenv root)/shims:$PATH

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/jcortizrh/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/jcortizrh/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/jcortizrh/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/jcortizrh/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: You need to add more info. What's your .zshrc look like? Specifically, where does it mention `pyenv` or something python related? That seems to be where the error is coming from, so editing it will likely be required to remove the error.

If you're concerned about breaking it, just make a backup.

Comment: Most likely you'll just have to remove entries with ```pyenv``` command in your ```.zshrc```.
Can you post your ```.zshrc``` here?

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchneider and @MonsieurMerso ! I edited the post to include my full `.zshrc` (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that removing the first line from my `.zshrc` solves the issue. Thanks for the suggestions!